# Passando map para método

Tags: java

Sou iniciante em Java e tenho feito alguns projetinhos como testes.

Nesse caso, andei lendo e achei interessando o map, mas, me embolei na hora de aplicar. 
Achei que seria um bom exemplo para eu me familiarizar.
Poderiam me ajudar como seria essa implementação?

```
private TesteCiclo buildTesteCiclo(Map<String, String> map, DateService dateService) {
    String id = map.get("id");
    long idCiclo = Long.parseLong(map.get("id_ciclo"));
    String descricao = map.get("descricao");
    String servico = map.get("servico");
    Long valorCobranca = obtemValorDaCobranca(descricao, id, idCiclo);
    return EventosMap.buildTesteCiclo(id, idCiclo, descricao, servico,dateService, valorCobranca);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O Map é diferente de uma lista em si, porque ao invés de ter índices numéricos (como em um vetor) você pode ter um índice de qualquer tipo. Como o próprio nome diz o Map vai mapear cada `key` para um `value`. Vou exemplificar:

Com um vetor você teria:

```
String[] vet = new String[]{"ola", "bom dia"};
System.out.println(vet[0]) // vai imprimir 'ola'
System.out.println(vet[1]) // vai imprimir 'bom dia'
```

Agora com map:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "ola");
map.put(1, "bom dia");
```

As duas estruturas são equivalentes, map.get(0) vai imprimir o mesmo que vet[0] e assim por diante.
O legal do Map é que você pode usar qualquer tipo de objeto como índice, no seu exemplo uma `String`. Esse índice, assim como nos vetores, é único.

Se você tiver:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Nome", "Joao");
map.put("Sobrenome", "Teste");
```

isso é como se você tivesse

```
map["Nome"] = "João";
```

Porém, se você fizer:

```
map.put("Nome", "Joao");
map.put("Nome", "Ola");
```

nesse caso você vai sobrescrever o valor associado à key `Nome`.

Espero que tenha entendido a ideia do Map.  Abraço

Comment: Ótima explicação. Muito obrigada!

Comment: obrigado, marque a resposta como aceita